# PHP e Javascript - Opções Sim e Não em popup de Confirm

Tags: php, javascript, confirm

No meu site, possuo uma seção de consulta de eventos. Dentro dessa seção, fiz a inclusão de um botão CANCELAR EVENTO. Quando esse botão é clicado, executa a seguinte função em javascript:

```
function cancelaEvento(val){
    var valor = val;
    if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja cancelar o evento "+val+"?\nCaso deseje fazer alguma alteração, clique em Editar") == true) {
        location.href = "http://meusite.com.br/consultaeventos/cancelar?valor="+valor;
    }
}
```

Mas eu queria que no popup de *confirm* aparecesse SIM e NÃO ou invés de OK e CANCELAR. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: A caixa de diálogo padrão não pode ser customizada por vias normais. É sempre OK e CANCEL. Pesquise por "javascript custom confirm", no google para soluções alternativas.

Comment: Exatamente, uma alternativa é usar dialogos do Jquery: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation. Ou implementar o próprio.

Comment: Parece que nativamente não é possível, mas pode ser usada uma biblioteca. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420935/javascript-custom-text-on-confirm-ok-cancel-button